# How to stop sound when I switch user

Tags: gnome, sound, notification, switch-user

When I switch users on my ubuntu 20.04 LTS laptop I get a very loud sound.  It sounds like a very quick trio of medium-pitched bells.

It's loud enough to wake my spouse up in the next room, and is unaffected by the volume setting or mute.  And it's useless - I *know* that I'm switching users, I don't need a stupid bell to inform me.

I don't want to turn off all notifications.  I like to get one when my battery power is low for example.  So, I haven't experimented with any blanket settings.

And I have about 20 applications set up for notifications - pretty much all default behavior. I suppose it could be any of these.  I have not experimented with any of these settings.

And I have experimented with dconf-editor, and trying turning the two audible settings to false:   /org/gnome/terminal/profiles/*/audible-bell and /org/gnome/desktop/vm/preferences/audible-bell - neither made any difference.  I see no sound config for user-switching.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04) had 5 years of *standard* support life, is nearing the end of those five years. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm if your system is still *supported*. Either way, if the machine is on-line, you should plan to *release-upgrade* asap unless you plan to use ESM/Pro, but please note ESM/Pro releases are not on-topic here when standard support ends.

Comment: Online tools like https://packages.ubuntu.com/ no longer provide details for anything older than 20.04 as the five years of support for *bionic* or 18.04 ended last month, so our ability to help is even more limited now. We'd need to have a *bionic* system around (to do enquiries at terminal) or have *devscripts* installed that allow searching of ESM releases such as 18.04 (*18.04 ESM official start date is 31-May-2023 so you're on-topic on this site until then*).  I'd suggest planning your *release-upgrade* asap too.

Comment: This machine has been in a closet for a year and I'm just updating it to give to somebody. I just now updated it to 20.04 - and the problem is unchanged.   Any thoughts on the problem with the obnoxious sound?

Comment: There are a number of login sounds available selected by the user; a default one used long ago maybe this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NL3c4l6G6pM) but the installation media set the default. It's just a mp3 file that is played on login; remove it from your startup jobs & it'll be quiet (setup jobs can be desktop/wm or environment specific)  *You could hae a look in System Settings .. Sound .. Sound Effects and see if anything is ticked; or in Startup Application Preferences etc*